# Highchart : How to set different step on each xaxis label?

Tags: highcharts

I have sample of array data below :

```
[
 [10,10.23],
 [23,58.55],
 ...,
 [-30,170.66],
 ...,
 [-13,3433.36],
 ...,
 [4,47449.77],
 ...
]
```

When I generate them to graph, the xaxis label was set to :

```
0, 5k, 10k, 15k, 20k, 25k, 30k, etc
```

I would like to set step for xaxis label like :

```
0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000
```

or in logic code equal to :

```
Math.pow(10,step+1)
```

I read the Highchart API, never found the solution for this step method. Is there a trick to do that?

Thank you,
Mahdi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'logarithmic',
    labels: { //for if you want to hide the 'k' abbreviation for thousands
        '{value}'
    }
},
```

See the [HighCharts demo](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-log-axis) on logarithmic charts for more details.

Comment: hi, yup it works. just for additional info, it doesn't work with value 0, so I change this value > 0